# Delphi Firemonkey TListview ~ change color of TListItemText when item is selected

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

Delphi 10.4.1, in FMX `TListview`

```
LItemText := ListviewItem.Objects.FindDrawable('InvoiceTotal') as TListItemText;
LItemText.TextColor := ...
```

This works fine in `OnUpdateObjects` event, but when a particular row is shown as selected, Delphi auto change the color of TListItemText to black (which I don't want).

How do I over-ride this in code?  Or do I need to resort to `TStylebook` - which I find quite complicated?

Thanks.